# Android RecyclerView вечно грузит первый активный элемент

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть следующая проблема: в своём фрагменте динамически через inflate добавляю layout с горизонтальным RecyclerView внутри, используя следующий код:

```
  private void createEventsBanners(List<Banner> sliderItems) {
    View eventView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_home_banner_event_list, null);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = eventView.findViewById(R.id.banner_event_list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {
        @Override
        public boolean checkLayoutParams(RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp) {
            lp.width = (int) (getWidth() * 0.47);
            return true;
        }
    });
    BannerEventAdapter adapter = new BannerEventAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.setList(sliderItems);
    adapter.setListener(position -> {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("id", sliderItems.get(position).getEventId());
        controller.navigate(R.id.fragmentEvent, bundle);
    });
    contentContainer.addView(eventView);
}
```

Внутри RecyclerView следующая структура:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="243dp"
android:layout_marginStart="6.5dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="6.5dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="243dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/loader"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="invisible">

      <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/loader"
        />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Изображения подгружаются с помощью следующего кода:

```
 public static void loadImage(String item, ImageView image, View mainView) {
    ConstraintLayout loader = mainView.findViewById(R.id.loader);

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(mainView.getContext())
            .threadPoolSize(6)
            .threadPriority(7)
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisc(true)
                    .build())
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(10 * 1024 * 1024))
            .build();

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Получили экземпляр
    imageLoader.init(config); // Проинициализировали конфигом по умолчанию
    imageLoader.displayImage(item, image, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            loaderHide(loader);
            super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);
            loader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loader.setAlpha(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            super.onLoadingFailed(imageUri, view, failReason);
            loadImage(item, image, mainView);
        }
    }); // Запустили асинхронный показ картинки

}
```

Всё работает отлично, однако после перехода по нажатию на картинку на фрагмент с помощью navigation и возвращению назад то первый видимый элемент попадает в постоянный лоадер, хотя в метод для загрузки он не попадает, если прокрутить дальше и опять вернуться к этому элементу лоадер пропадёт. Как можно решить это? И почему это происходит?

Comment: Откуда вызывается loadImage?

Comment: onBindViewHolder

Comment: Хмм, пока мало информации, нужна воспроизводимка — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Готов всё что угодно предоставить, лишь бы эта проблема пропала